Some good books on statistical decision theory
What are some good books on statistical decision theory? I want good and tough maths problems using statistical decision theory and also has some good practical applications.
I am an undergrad in computer science and engineering, but am very interested in leading rigorous statistics so any journal book or course that should done will help me a lot.
